# Clearing an interval in a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple plugin that adds dots to a piece of text, i.e.

```
Loading.
Loading..
Loading...
Loading.
```

etc.

Here is my code (http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/waGzJb?editors=001):

```
$.fn.dotdotdots = function(options) {

  var settings = $.extend({
    speed: 300,
    dot_max: 3,
    reset: 0,
    string: '.'
  }, options );

  var default_text = this.text();
  var target = this;
  var dot_count = 0;

  setInterval(function(){

    var dots = '';

    for(var i = settings.reset; i < dot_count; i ++){
      dots += settings.string;
    }

    dot_count ++;
    if(dot_count > settings.dot_max){
      dot_count = settings.reset;
    }

    target.text(default_text + dots);
  }, settings.speed);

  return this;

};

$("#target").dotdotdots({'speed':400});
```

The issue is that after a while, I'd like to stop the `setInterval` within the plugin, from outside of it. My immediate thought was to try inside the function:

```
this.intId = setInterval(function(){
```

Then I could use something like:

```
clearInterval($("#target").intId);
```

Externally to stop the plugin doing its thing. But that isn't doing the trick... can anyone point me in the right direction?

To be honest I'm wondering if I need to make the plugin a little more complex and somehow use a `.start()` and `.stop()` function.

Comment: Assign your `setInterval()` to a variable, so you can call `clearInterval(the_variable)` when needed.

Comment: @kmsdev Like I did in my question? How do you access the variable which is created inside a plugin?

Comment: declare your `var` globally.

Comment: Its a plugin, I'd rather not require a global `var`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access to your setInterval variable, so assign the interval to a global (inside plugin) variable:

```
$.fn.dotdotdots.Interval = setInterval(...)
```

Then you can clear it:

```
clearInterval($.fn.dotdotdots.Interval)
```

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha. I guess really I should still make my start and stop functions to make things a bit more readable, but that makes total sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Only you would need to create a variable with the use setInterval and clearInterval when a condition is fulfilled .

An example :

```js
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){

    var dots = '';

    for(var i = settings.reset; i < dot_count; i ++){
      dots += settings.string;
    }

    dot_count ++;
    if(dot_count > settings.dot_max){
      dot_count = settings.reset;
     
    }

    target.text(default_text + dots);
  }, settings.speed);

if(true) clearInterval(myInterval);
```